# What is the angle of ABD?

Tags: geometry

Beth draws $5$ points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ on a circle as well as the tangent to the circle at $A$, such that all angles marked with $x$ are equal.
What is the angle of $ABD$?

Comment: Can you divulge where the angles marked $x$ are?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is beginning to attract down-votes and close-votes, probably because it is simply an isolated problem statement (and one that is missing key details). Please always strive to state something of what you know about a problem and/or where you got stuck. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard with no diagram or knowing which angles are marked $x$, though in my imagination you could have something like this, where $x=\frac{180^\circ}{5}=36^\circ$ and all the other shown angles are $x$ or multiples of $x$

In particular $\angle ABD = 72^\circ$

[image]

*Added:* You can easily show that a regular pentagon has all five $x$s equal using the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). Since the $x$s determine the shape of the pentagon, no irregular pentagon can have this property.  This extends easily to other polygons and for $n$ sides and $n$ equal $x$s you would have $x=\frac{180^\circ}{n}$ and $\angle ABD = (n-3)x = \frac{n-3}{n} 180^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a regular pentagon. Angle subtnded at center is $ \dfrac{360}{5}=72^{\circ}$ and angle subtented at circle boundary is half that angle $ =36^{\circ}$